# how to get clicked element text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to get the text of clicked element in an alert of jQuery. See example below
https://jsfiddle.net/pymd4n04/2/

```
jQuery(".results").click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).find('h3').click(function() {
      var text = jQuery(this).text();
console.log(text.trim());
alert(text.trim());
    });
});
```

But when I click first time, empty alert is shown and when I click 2nd the value is shown but twice alert. and keep increment alerts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/pymd4n04/3/

Comment: Why you set `click` event on `.results` ? It just need to get text of `h3` on click. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pymd4n04/5/) Also if you want to prevent to redirecting to links, you should set `event` on function.

Comment: Great. This works fine

Comment: When I add event.preventDefault(); see jsFiddle, it works fine. But the same code when I add it in wordpress header the event.preventDefault(); does not work and I redirect to another page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all of your links are embedded inside `h3` elements you can be more specific in your jQuery to retrieve all `h3` elements that are inside another element with the class name `.results` like so:

```
jQuery(".results h3").click(function() {
```

Secondly, in your code you're using two click functions... which is not necessary.  With the line of code above.. once you click on an `h3` element inside an element with the class name `.results` then you can easily grab the text of that `h3` element like so:

```
jQuery(".results h3").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var text = jQuery(this).text(); // 'this' refers to the h3 element that you clicked.. not the div with the class .results
    alert(text.trim());
});
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pymd4n04/7/).

Comment: This is great. But event.preventDefault(); is not working on my wordpress site. While it is working in jsFiddle. Any idea?

Comment: Well, in the code you provided in your question.. you did not include the `event` in your click function:  `.click(function(event)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use so many click events, just easier : `jQuery(".asp_res_url").click(function() {});`

This works:

```js
jQuery(".asp_res_url").click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
alert( jQuery(this).text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results" style="height: 460px; overflow-y: auto;">

        
        <div class="resdrg"><div class="item asp_result_pagepost asp_an_fadeIn">
    <div class="asp_content">
            <a class="asp_res_image_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                <div class="asp_image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://einsteam.com/#contactus&quot;);">
                    <div class="void"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <h3><a class="asp_res_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                Real Estate                                <span class="overlap"></span>
                        </a></h3>
        <div class="etc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="asp_spacer"></div><div class="item asp_result_pagepost asp_an_fadeIn">
    <div class="asp_content">
            <a class="asp_res_image_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                <div class="asp_image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://einsteam.com/#contactus&quot;);">
                    <div class="void"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <h3><a class="asp_res_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                E-Commerce                                <span class="overlap"></span>
                        </a></h3>
        <div class="etc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="asp_spacer"></div><div class="item asp_result_pagepost asp_an_fadeIn">
    <div class="asp_content">
            <a class="asp_res_image_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                <div class="asp_image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://einsteam.com/#contactus&quot;);">
                    <div class="void"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <h3><a class="asp_res_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                Retail                                <span class="overlap"></span>
                        </a></h3>
        <div class="etc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="asp_spacer"></div><div class="item asp_result_pagepost asp_an_fadeIn">
    <div class="asp_content">
            <a class="asp_res_image_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                <div class="asp_image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://einsteam.com/#contactus&quot;);">
                    <div class="void"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <h3><a class="asp_res_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                Payment Industry                                <span class="overlap"></span>
                        </a></h3>
        <div class="etc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="asp_spacer"></div><div class="item asp_result_pagepost asp_an_fadeIn">
    <div class="asp_content">
            <a class="asp_res_image_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                <div class="asp_image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://einsteam.com/#contactus&quot;);">
                    <div class="void"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <h3><a class="asp_res_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                Field Service                                <span class="overlap"></span>
                        </a></h3>
        <div class="etc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="asp_spacer"></div><div class="item asp_result_pagepost asp_an_fadeIn">
    <div class="asp_content">
            <a class="asp_res_image_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                <div class="asp_image" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://einsteam.com/#contactus&quot;);">
                    <div class="void"></div>
                </div>
            </a>
        <h3><a class="asp_res_url" href="https://einsteam.com/contact/">
                SAS                                <span class="overlap"></span>
                        </a></h3>
        <div class="etc">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="asp_spacer"></div></div>

        
    </div>
```