# How to get selected td data from a loop in jsp to JS file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following jsp code.

```
...
<c:forEach var="empData" items="${employees}">
<tr> 
    <td><a href="#" id="nameId">${empData.name}</a></td>
    <td>${empData.age}</td>
</tr> 
</c:forEach>
...
```

And I've a separate JS file with the following code snippet

```
$('#nameId').on('click', function(e) {
   //Here I want to get dat for both name and age
})
```

So, here in the js file, how the get both name and age?

**Edited**: I've edited the code.
Note: I'm using JSP, and JavaScript

Comment: "JQuery get element text" would have been a good search...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
$('#nameId').on('click', function(e) {
   //Here I want to get the empData.name
   alert(e.target.text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="nameId">DEF</a>
```

Comment: I've edited the code. Could you please check

Answer (score 0):

In the event listener you can use `e.target.innerText` to access the text contained in the `<a>` tag.

You can do it also with jQuery by calling `$(e.target).text()`

Comment: I've edited the code. Could you please check?

Comment: The answer remains the same. Also this question is a duplicate of [how to get clicked element text using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467307/how-to-get-clicked-element-text-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the big jquery overhead to achieve your desired outcome.

Simply do this:

```
document.getElementById('nameId').addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
   alert(e.target.text);
});
```

Look at this page if you want to step away from jquery
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: I've edited the code.

Comment: I think I have to clarify: In case you use jQuery in your project anyway it's fine and convenient to use but if you add jQuery to your project just to do simple selections it's not necessary as you can see ^^